# PDF of product of two continous joint distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity

Suppose that $X1$ and $X2$ have a continuous joint distribution for which
the joint PDF is as follows:

\begin{equation*}
f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases} 
       x_1 + x_2 & \text {for $0 < x_1 < 1,$ and $0 < x_2 < 1$}\\
       0    & \text {otherwise}\\
       \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Find the PDF of $Y = X_1 X_2 $.

Comment: Looked up wikipedia?

Comment: Can you please guide me through the steps ?

Comment: What are the definitions and what haev you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it. Let $F_Y$ the CDF of $Y$.

$$F_Y(t) = P(Y \leq t) = P \left(X_1 X_2 \leq t \right) = P \left(X_2 \leq \dfrac{t}{X_1} \right).$$

If you plot $x_2 = t/x_1$:

[image]

you see that there is a range for $t$: $0 \le t \le 1$.

So the CDF of $Y$ is:

$$\iint_D f_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) dA = \iint_D (x_1 + x_2) dA.$$

We need the limits for $x_1$ and $x_2$. When $x_2=1$, then $x_1 = t$, so there are two regions to integrate: the first one is $0 \le x_1 \le t$ and $0 \le x_2 \le 1$; the second one is $t \le x_1 \le 1$ and $0 \le x_2 \le t/x_1$:

$$\iint_D f_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) dA = \int_{0}^t \int_0^1 (x_1 + x_2) dx_1 dx_2 +  \int_{t}^1 \int_0 \limits^{t/x_1} (x_1 + x_2) dx_2 dx_1, $$

$$= \dfrac{t^2}{2}+ \dfrac{t}{2} + t - \dfrac{t^2}{2} -t^2 + \dfrac{t}{2},$$

$$=2t-t^2.$$

So the PDF of $Y$:

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}F_Y(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt}(2t - t^2) = 2-2t.$$

You can check that:

$$\int_0^1 (2-2t) dt = 1.$$